# my date difference Function working in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have date in the format

```
06-Feb-2013
```

Actually what i am doing is i have a date in format `06-Feb-2013` and i have to calculate the difference between current date and given date in terms of years and months.

The code below is what i am using, but this code is working fine in **chrome** but not in **firefox**,:

```
var d =  new Date();
var StartedDriving = "06-Feb-2013";

if(StartedDriving != 0){
    var dd= new  Date(StartedDriving);
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(d.getTime() - dd.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    var n =(diffDays/365);  
    var y = Math.floor(n);            // whole years
    var m = Math.floor(12 * (n - y)); // treat remainder as fraction of a year
    var Experience = document.getElementById("exp");
    Experience.innerHTML = y +" Years ,"+ m + " Months";
}
```

Iam getting output as
**Chrome**:
[image: Chrome output]

**Firefox:**
[image: Firefox output]

Is there a way i can make it work in both chrome and firefox.

[JSfiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/sandeepb/16r4pkx7/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass ISO date format `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` to make sure date function parse string properly.

[Check updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/16r4pkx7/1/)

If you are making other operations with date and time its better to use library like [momemt.js](http://momentjs.com/) instead of using vanilla js.

I haven't tested above fiddle with IE.